# progress bar is not updating in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-progressbar

i'm using progress bar with countdown timer, everything is working fine except progress bar animation it not working in animation form, its just updating its state after the duration not in animation. Please somebody help me for this problem.

**Here is my code**

```
   countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(oneMin,1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(final long millisUntilFinished)
        {
         /*   long finishedSeconds = oneMin - millisUntilFinished;
            int total = (int) (((float)finishedSeconds / (float)oneMin) * 100.0);
            progressBar.setProgress(total);*/
            progressBar.setMax(100);
             progress = 1000*60/10;
progressBar.setProgress(progress);

            }

            @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            //t1.setText("");
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "your score", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            dia1();

            progressBar.setProgress(0);
        }
    };

    tt2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(ans.equals("1"))
            {
                countDownTimer.cancel();
                mp.start();


                Random r = new Random();
                i1 = r.nextInt(10 - 1) + 1;
                colorDetails(i1);
                i++;
                tt5.setText(String.valueOf("Score:"+i));
                countDownTimer.start();
            }
```

Comment: Your progress value doesn't change is why. You always set `progress = 6000`.

Comment: with every tick of your counter you're setting the same progress on your bar so nothing changes. You need to provide a way to provide different values with every tick, so you can see the difference

Comment: can you please give me an example

Answer (score 0):

- You `setMax` your progress bar 100 and then you `setProgress` 6000 !! which is over the max value
- Your progress bar will stop at the same progress every time you call `onTick` method because that method update the same value evey time you call it
  Read  [this](https://www.journaldev.com/9629/android-progressbar-example) to read some examples 
  about progress bar